# What is the most optimized way to use D3 with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, data-visualization

I know that this is a common topic but this is narrowing down the main options out there.

**Which option below provides the best performance when using D3 inside a React.js app?**

- Place D3 within the **React Lifecycle method hooks or React 16 Hooks** to update the state: componentDidMount or useState. (And use Redux)
- Use the **react-faux-dom** approach.

> The concept is that D3 is fed a fake DOM which implements all methods
>   it would expect the DOM to have. That fake DOM is manipulated by D3
>   and then automatically rendered as React elements stored into the
>   component’s state where React can pick up changes and kick-off an
>   update, including lifecycle methods and reconciliation as you would
>   expect.
>   [Thibaut Tiberghien](https://medium.com/@tibotiber)

- To use a **React D3 Library** that is component based. For example: [vx library](https://vx-demo.now.sh/)

Comment: Try [react-vis](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/) if you want a d3-based react graphing library instead of rolling your own

Comment: Thank you @technogeek1995! I've heard of it before, but I will check it out. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach that i found was to let d3 do the calculations and pass rendering part to react.js.

I have a codesndbox sample, if you would like to give it a try.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/wq2nw3lmml